# CSS - How to stack media elements on top of one another

Tags: css

I have a web app using [Bootstrap 5](https://v5.getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/position/) that includes 2 images and 1 video. The two images look like a retro TV. The first image is the "back" of the TV. The second image is the frame on top of the screen of the TV. The video is basically what is supposed to be shown on the *screen* of the TV. Based on these images, I basically need to "stack" them on top of one another. In an attempt to do this, I've done the following:

```
<div class="position-relative top-0 left-0" style="transform: scale(0.67);">
  <img src="/images/tv-back.png" class="position-relative top-0 left-0" />
  <video height="100%" width="auto" autoplay loop muted class="position-absolute left-75 top-0" style="z-index:1;">
    <source src="/videos/sample.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  </video>
  <img src="/images/tv-front.png" class="position-relative top-0 left-0" style="z-index:2;" />
</div>
```

Oddly, the three elements do not stack on top of each other. I cannot figure out why. All of this looks correct. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: reset display to block ;) ... `position-absolute left-75 top-0` what is the final purpose here ?

Comment: @G-Cyrillus What element(s) did you apply `position-absolute` to? Oddly, as soon as I apply `position-absolute` on the first `img` element, nothing appears. When I flip it back to `position-relative`, I see all three elements, however, they are incorrectly layed out.

Comment: i did not, i'm asking about those rules, why do you use them ? it's along your video tag ... Is that your code or did you copy/paste it from somewhere else ?

Comment: @G-Cyrillus That's my code. Things weren't working, so I started to randomly plug in values trying to get something to work.

Comment: https://codepen.io/thewhitegrizzzzli/pen/QWEEoNy

Comment: @LaurentC Thank you for your response. However, when I view this, I see Mario, above a video, above a third image. However, I do not see them on *layered* (i.e. stacked) top of one another. Parts of my images are transparent, which is why I'm trying to layer / stack them to create an overlay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first img and video elements need to be positioned absolutely so the elements stack one on top of the other. Also, video elements seem to have a slightly different treatment within a stacking context (note that the transform creates a new stacking context) - they do not follow the normal order (at least on the browser I am currently using, Edge) and they take up top position even if their z-index is set to lower than the last element - unless they are given a z-index less than 0.

I have replaced the classes in the code by inline styles just so it is obvious what is happening here:

```
<div style="position: relative; top: 0; left: 0; transform: scale(0.67);">
  <img src="/images/tv-back.png" style="position:absolute; top: 0; left: 0; z-index:-2;" />
  <video height="100%" width="auto" autoplay loop muted style="position: absolute; left: 75px; top: 0; z-index: -1;">
    <source src="/videos/sample.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  </video>
  <img src="/images/tv-front.png" style="position: relative; top: 0; left: 0; z-index: 1;" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.position-relative {
  display: flex!important;
  flex-direction: column!important;
}

img {
  width: 45%;
  height: 45%
}

video {
  width: 45%;
  height: 45%;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="position-relative top-0 left-0" style="transform: scale(0.67);">
  <img src="https://gamasutra.com/db_area/images/news/320213/Super-Mario-64.jpg" class="position-relative top-0 left-0" />
  <video height="100%" width="auto" autoplay loop muted class="left-75 top-0" style="z-index:1;">
      <source src="https://cdn.videvo.net/videvo_files/video/free/2013-07/small_watermarked/hd0079_preview.webm" type="video/webm" />
   </video>
  <img src="/images/tv-front.png" class="position-relative top-0 left-0" style="z-index:2;" />
</div>
```

You remove 'position-absolute' in the inline styling and you add the above CSS code thank you.

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, when I view this, I see Mario, above a video, above a third image. However, I do not see them on *layered* top of one another

Comment: just remove the margin? line 14

Comment: https://codepen.io/thewhitegrizzzzli/pen/QWEEoNy updated

Comment: if you want to overlap them just give the child items in the .position-relative container a negative top and bottom margins like this `.position-relative > * {margin:-25px 0;}`